# IBMMQDotnetClient + IBM MQ 7.5: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED when runs as another user

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, ibm-mq

We successfully use IBMMQDotnetClient in out .NET application to connect with IBM MQ 7.5. The application runs as a specific user (for example, "ibm_mq_manager_user") on a Windows server or a developer's Windows desktop. The .NET code snippet is:

```
var queueManagerOptions = new Hashtable {
    { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
    { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _settings.HostName },
    { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _settings.ChannelName },
    { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _settings.Port }
};
var mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_settings.QueueManagerName, queueManagerOptions);
```

We are moving the application to a Linux server where it runs as another user. The code produces an error **MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE**.

I guess, I should specify the user "ibm_mq_manager_user" in queueManagerOptions. However, the next change causes an error **MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED** even on a developer's Windows desktop when the application runs as another user:

```
var queueManagerOptions = new Hashtable {
    { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
    { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, _settings.HostName },
    { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, _settings.ChannelName },
    { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, _settings.Port },
    { MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "ibm_mq_manager_user" } // the change
};
var mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_settings.QueueManagerName, queueManagerOptions);
```

What should I do to successfully connect to the IBM MQ Manager in the application that runs as another user than "ibm_mq_manager_user" (change Windows authentication to login/password authentication)?

Answer (score 1):

> The code produces an error **MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE**.

That reason code means that either the queue manager is not running or you are using the wrong hostname (IP address) or port number.

> the next change causes an error **MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED** even on a developer's Windows desktop when the application runs as another user:

Putting the UserId & Password in the connection parameters is ONLY used for authentication.

For .NET application, authorization (not authentication) is performed against the UserId that the application is running under.

If you want the queue manager to use the UserId that you set in the connection properties, then you MUST change ADOPTCTX to YES.

You should read the following IBM MQ pages:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=authentication-connection-configuration

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=records-interaction-chlauth-connauth

Comment: It is problemmatic to configure the queue manager on the IBM MQ Server unfortunately. I can only rewrite the .NET client side. IBM MQ Explorer successfully connects to the queue manager when userId is specified without password. Is it possible to reproduce the IBM MQ Explorer logic in my .NET application without reconfiguring the server side?

Comment: MQ Explorer is written in Java. The Java client library for IBM MQ uses the UserId that is set in the connection parameters for authorization. For .NET, C/C++/COBOL/Python etc. applications, the MQ client library uses the UserId that the client application is running under for authorization. It is just one of those quirks that you need to understand.  The simplest solution is to create the required UserId on the server where you are running the application, then run the application under that UserId.